# Unprocessable entity in Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I need to make an ajax request to change the "status" parameter of my "task" object.
the script, that's right, i can get the id of the task and the new status, that's all i need. however, I believe that the error is in the routes.rb files or in the update_status function that I put in the controller, or even in the ajax url, anyway. it is giving the following error: jquery-1.12.4.js:10254 PATCH http://127.0.0.1:3000/tasks/13/update_status 422 (Unprocessable Entity)

js and ajax in index.html.erb:

```
    <script>
    $(function() {
      var taskId;
      $(".drag").draggable({
        revert: "invalid",
        start: function(event, ui) {
          // Stores the task ID when the drag starts
          taskId = ui.helper.data("task-id");
        }
      });
    
      $(".box").droppable({
        accept: ".drag",
        drop: function(event, ui) {
          // When a child div is dropped onto a parent div
          $(this).append(ui.helper); // Move a div filha para a div pai
    
    
          // Get the new status based on the parent div
          var newStatus = $(this).attr("id");
          // Simulate an AJAX request to update task status
          console.log("Tarefa " + taskId + " movida para " + newStatus);
    
          $.ajax({
          url: "/tasks/" + taskId + "/update_status",
          method: "PATCH", 
          data: { task: { status: newStatus } },
          success: function(response) {
              console.log(response);
          }
    
        });
        }
      });
      });
    </script>
    <%= link_to "New task", new_task_path %>
```

file routes.db:

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
      resources :tasks do
        member do
          patch 'update_status' # Nome da rota personalizada
        end
      end 
      root to: "static_pages#index"
    end
```

part of the file tasks_controller.rb:

```
    def update
        respond_to do |format|
          if @task.update(task_params)
            format.html { redirect_to task_url(@task), notice: "Task was successfully updated." }
            format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @task }
          else
            format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end
    
      def update_status
        @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    
        # Verifique se o status fornecido é válido (você pode adicionar suas próprias validações aqui)
        new_status = params[:status]
    
        @task.update(status: new_status)
    
      end
```

I tried to change the status with ajax and I got an unprocessable entity

Comment: why don't you just patch/put to `"/tasks/" + taskId`. *update_status* action seems unnecessary.

Comment: Because when I type the rails routes command in the cmd it appears that the route is: update_status_task PATCH /tasks/:id/update_status(.:format). Anyway, I tried to do that too but it gives the same error.

Comment: @what Alex is saying is that the non-standard route is completely superflous.

Answer (score 1):

The code likely raises an error beause it doesn't use [`StrongParameters`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters).

I suggest changing it to:

```
  def update_status
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])

    new_status = params.require(:task).permit(:status)

    @task.update(status: new_status)
  end
```

Comment: I tried that but it still didn't work

Comment: in addition, I programmed it to display a console.log("I got here") as soon as it reaches the update_status function, but it does not print this message, so it probably does not even reach this function

Comment: Then it might be a `before_action` that is failing - authentication, for example. What does the log file entry (in `log/development.log` for that request look like? What does the body of the response (not just the status code) look like? And did you try to change `create` to `create!`)?